# Empty value in Excel cell?

Tags: java, excel, ms-office

I have a java program which receives .xlsx (Excel file) as an input.

Somehow I manage to create some, lets say, "strange empty state" in one of the cells crucial for work of my program. By that, I mean that cell looks perfectly empty and cause program to has behavior A.

However, If I mark that disputable cell, press "delete" button (try to empty content) from keyboard upon it and save document, program has different behavior B.

Any idea which value could be initially in the cell which looks perfectly empty?
And how is possible that simple deleting changes content of the cell?
Any idea what to do?

Comment: How about adding code in your java program to look for valid data and always give you "Behavior B"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three different ways in a cell can **appear** empty, but actually not be empty.

Start with a clean, new, worksheet and in cell **B1** enter:

```
=ISBLANK(A1)
```

then copy **B1** to **B2** and **B3**  They will all show *True*

Then in **A1** enter the formula:

```
=""
```

*Copy* **A1** and *PasteSpecialValues* onto cell **A2**

Then enter a single quote character in cell **A3**

The cells in column **A** will appear empty, but the cells in column **B** will now show *False!*

**EDIT#1**

From *VBA* pick a cell and run:

```
Sub GhostFinder()

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
    MsgBox "genuine blank!"
    Exit Sub
End If
With ActiveCell
If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "something is there"
    Exit Sub
End If
If .HasFormula Then
    MsgBox "formula returning blank"
    Exit Sub
End If
If .PrefixCharacter <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Prefix character present"
    Exit Sub
End If
End With
MsgBox "Null present"
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, using the =ISBLANK(<myField>) I confirmed that my field is definitely not blank. But I am still not sure what is inside...

Comment: function field is also completely blank.

Comment: Ok. It showed me the null value. Is there any posibillity that user somehow manualy insert the null value? I can not find a way to recreate the problem...

Comment: @Filip .......It is not likely that the User manually entered a *Null.*  The User most likely copied a column of formulas and PasteSpecialValues elsewhere.